# Dequeue method affecting for loop (Java)

Tags: java

I have a method in which I'm using quite a few other classes, including a Linked List, a queue, and a stack. In my method, I have a for loop in which I want to pop my stack (conveniently named s) and dequeue my queue (conveniently named q) into s1 and q1. For some reason, the dequeue is messing up the program and the loop is only running half as many times as it should. Here's some code to make this clear

```
    public E dequeue() {

    if (manyItems == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    SNode<E> temp = front;
    front = front.getNext();
    manyItems--;
    return (E) temp.getElement();   

}
```

I would also like to say that I tested my entire Queue class earlier in the program with an integer queue and it worked perfectly, dequeue included. I'm not sure what's wrong. If I haven't made something clear enough or if I need to provide more code (there's a LOT more, I just though I'd include the critical pieces), please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Create [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: when you say q.dequeue(), I guess that will change the size of q so q.getManyItems() will return a smaller size. So the loop will eventually terminate earlier than you expected.

Comment: Your problem is with a loop and you just edited your question to get rid of the problem code!?

Answer (score 3):

Your loop is finishing halfway through because you are both incrementing `j` and decrementing the size of the queue each time through the loop. These two counters cross when the queue is half emptied.

You probably want this:

```
while (q.getManyItems() > 0) {
    s1 = s.pop();
    q1 = q.dequeue();//***
}
```

If you need to keep a `for` loop with a counter (because of other stuff in the loop body that you haven't shown us), change the code to:

```
final int count = q.getManyItems();
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    s1 = s.pop();
    q1 = q.dequeue();//***
}
```